# if(!q || q === '*') why wildcard use as a string here?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
search(q: string): Observable<any> {
if(!q || q === '*') {
  q = '';
} else {
  q = q.toLowerCase();
}
```

In if condition, why wildcard use as a string here? Please explain this things.

Comment: Search '*' = search empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regular expression search for empty value, including spaces and tabs /^\s*$/ . Regular expressions do not exclusively use "*", this is the number of matches from 0 to infinity.

```js
console.log(/^\s*$/.test(""));
console.log(/^\s*$/.test(" "));
console.log(/^\s*$/.test("*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's actually working. It's actually working like a regular string comparator where it matching with "*" .

please see the reference https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

That is not a wildcard. `*` is a regular string. What that function does is takes string `q` as an argument, if it is undefined or null or empty or equal to `*`, then it will simply return empty string otherwise it will return lowercase of string `q`